# Jboss CLI application deployment

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, jboss-cli

I need to deploy a WAR file in JBOSS using CLI and want to send a JVM command line parameter that is used in the application. The CLI command for the deployment is:

`deploy --name=xxx-api.war --server-groups=server-group1 /war/locn/xxx-api-$rel_name.war`

I need to pass the below a java command line parameter:
`-Dspring.profiles.active=enableScheduler`

How can it be done?

Answer (score 1):

you can't set system property with jboss-cli deploy command. When you running jboss-cli JVM has already started. You should set properties in $JBOSS_HOME/bin/standalone.conf (or domain.conf). Or you could run java code to set system properties. You could define a servlet that loads on startup and set system property in servlet init method.

```
@WebServlet(name = "Prop", urlPatterns = {"/Prop"}, loadOnStartup = 1)
public class SetProperies extends HttpServlet {

@Override
public void init() throws ServletException {
    System.setProperty("spring.profiles.active", "enableScheduler");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

```
/server-group=server-group1/system-property=spring.profiles.active:add(boot-time=false, value="enableScheduler")
```

Comment: what does `boot-time` do? what is the consequence if setting it true?

Comment: The boot-time attribute is used in domain mode to have the host controller spawn new EAP instances with system properties on the JVM invocation that the boot-time attribute set to true. It has no downside in domain mode.